# Как получить ID поста отправленного в канале но в группе канала? Код на pyrogram

Tags: python, pyrogram

```
@client.on_message(filters.text & filters.channel)  
 
    async def post_handler(_, message):  
 
        if 'test' in message.chat.title:  
 
            channel = await client.get_chat(message.chat.id)  
 
            await client.send_message(channel.linked_chat.id, 'test', reply_to_message_id=message.id)
```

Без `ID` поста в группе прокомментировать правильный пост не получиться.